# Apache server is not starting

Tags: python, django, apache

I have one python Django project on our intranet server folder like "//xxx.com/.../myproject/", and I set up virtual env under it as python interpreter "//xxx.com/.../myproject/py37-venv".

I installed WampServer on my desktop computer (windows 10) and also on one windows server 2016, and testing apache server for Django server deployment.

I followed this article to test apache: https://www.codementor.io/@aswinmurugesh/deploying-a-django-application-in-windows-with-apache-and-mod_wsgi-uhl2xq09e

1. Added the following into `httpd.conf:`

   ```
   LoadFile "C:/Python/Python37_64//python37.dll"

   LoadModule wsgi_module "//xxx.com/.../myproject/py37-venv/lib/site-packages/mod_wsgi/server/mod_wsgi.cp37-win_amd64.pyd"

   WSGIPythonHome "//xxx.com/.../myproject/py37-venv"
   ```
2. Replace all 80 ports in `httpd.conf` to `8888`.
3. I tested with `httpd.exe -t`, reported "`Syntax ok`"
4. I tested with `httpd.exe -e debug`, it stopped and exit after this as below. I guess it is supposed to be continuously running after "generating secret...", right? It seems crashed although the modules loaded successfully:

> .......
>
> [Mon Feb 22 20:33:21.815182 2021] [so:debug] [pid 18624:tid 776]
> mod_so.c(266): AH01575: loaded module vhost_alias_module from
> C:/wamp64_323/bin/apache/apache2.4.46/modules/mod_vhost_alias.so
>
> [Mon Feb 22 20:33:21.817180 2021] [so:debug] [pid 18624:tid 776]
> mod_so.c(266): AH01575: loaded module php7_module from
> C:/wamp64_323/bin/php/php7.3.21/php7apache2_4.dll
>
> [Mon Feb 22 20:33:21.829179 2021] [so:debug] [pid 18624:tid 776]
> mod_so.c(336): AH01576: loaded file C:/Python/Python37_64/python37.dll
>
> [Mon Feb 22 20:33:21.878180 2021] [so:debug] [pid 18624:tid 776]
> mod_so.c(266): AH01575: loaded module wsgi_module from
> //xxx.com/.../py37-venv/Lib/site-packages/mod_wsgi/server/mod_wsgi.cp37-win_amd64.pyd
>
> [Mon Feb 22 20:33:21.879186 2021] [auth_digest:debug] [pid 18624:tid
> 776] mod_auth_digest.c(371): AH01757: generating secret for digest
> authentication

5. I tried: `httpd.exe -k start -n "Apache"`, returned nothing.
6. I tried to start it on the services panel, but it told me that it cannot be started on a local computer.

Does it seem something is wrong, Any ideas?